# Generate texts in build time

Tags: next.js, i18next

I have implement i18next in my project, but when generating the text in build time, instead of inserting the text, it add the variable and then it resolves in execution time.

This is my next-18next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'es',
    locales: ['es', 'en'],
    ns: ['common']
  },
};
```

I imported this in my next config like this.

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');
const nextConfig = {
 i18n
};
 
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

In my [..uri] page i have the getStaticProps:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ locale, params }) {
  const ruta = `/${params.uri?.join('/')}`;

  const { page, posts, configuraciones, CabeceraES, PieES, CabeceraEN, PieEN } =
    await getPage(ruta);

  const traductionProps = await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common']);

  return {
    props: {
      page,
      posts,
      configuraciones,
      CabeceraES,
      PieES,
      CabeceraEN,
      PieEN,
      ...traduccionProps,
    },
    revalidate: 500,
    notFound: !page,
  };
}
```

With this code above i want the value inserted, but it inserts the key and then resolves it:

```
<div style="display:absolute">components.atoms.characteristicsPost.averageReadingLast</div>
```

Instead of that i want it like this

```
<div style="display:absolute">12 mins</div>
```

The code works, it resolves it, but it triggers the t to translate it

Comment: Is `components.atoms.characteristicsPost.averageReadingLast` the name of a prop or a variable? Because if so you need to wrap it in `{}` inside your JSX.

Comment: its the code after the build. It should insert the 12 mins instead of the variabel name

Comment: As previously mentioned above, if this is a variable you need to wrap it between curly braces inside your JSX. Like this: `{components.atoms.characteristicsPost.averageReadingLast}`.

Comment: As i mentioned, in the component.js i had it like that, but after the build i want it to insert the value directly instead of inseting the component

Comment: I do not understand your line of questioning, could you rephrase that?